# best peer to peer technique for mobile network

Tags: networking, p2p, nat, hole-punching

I deal with design of **peer to peer** communication between mobile unit and user phone. Mobile unit is targeted into cars, so it is possible that it could be connected to many various ISPs. It can be also expected that the clients will be often disconnects. I need to find best solution in NAT traversal techniques, which is applicable in conditions of mobile network, which are little different than the usual networks as WiFi. I search for often used techniques and found a many different practices, such as *TCP* or *UDP Hole Punching*, *NUTSS*, *NATBLASTER*, *NatTrav* or official protocols such as STUN or ICE.

Could anyone advise me tried and proven technique under similar conditions?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

To achieve peer to peer(P2P) or relay connectivity you need to implement a protocol called ICE. This protocol allows you the ability of 100% NAT traversal. This is the best solution currently exist. You need to have STUN/TURN server as well.

With even the best solution ICE, you will not get 100% P2P connectivity between peers. Some connection will be established through a relay server called TURN. This depends on the type of NATs the peers are behind.

TCP or UDP Hole Punching is a special technique to allow some connection which normally would have been relay to be P2P. There are other techniques like that but those come after you implement ICE and have STUN/TURN server.

There are lots of open source STUN/TURN server and some companies provides solution for ICE. Some companies provide the whole NAT traversal solution providing ICE implementation and STUN/TURN server support.

Answer (score 1):

Other than TURN, you can also try UDP multi-hole punching, although it may be "too unreliable to be worth the hassle"

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1IimJ20gG0SY2NvaE4wRVVMbG8/view?usp=sharing